# MojoExecutionException while doing a build - Maven

Tags: java, maven, liferay, maven-3, liferay-6

Below is the goals that i have included while building maven project in my pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mynewproject.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-myfacts-portlet</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ABC MY FACTS Portlet</name>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-css</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>




        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <!-- Liferay dependency -->    
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>                  
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
         <!--  <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Portlet/JSR dependency -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet/JSP dependency -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>          
        </dependency> 

        <!-- Spring dependency -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- Unit testing -->       
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>  
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>  
            <version>1.9.5</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>junit</groupId>  
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
            <version>4.11</version>  
        </dependency>   

         <!-- Data Service dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mynewproject.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc-mynewproject-service</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mynewproject.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>emailcomponent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>Liferay-v6.2-EE-(Tomcat-7)</id>
    <properties>
        <liferay.version>6.2.2</liferay.version>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>7.0.0-m2</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>..\Liferay Portal\liferay-portal-6.2.10.1-ee-ga1\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>..\Liferay Portal\liferay-portal-6.2.10.1-ee-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>..\Liferay Portal\liferay-portal-6.2.10.1-ee-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\lib\ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>..\Liferay Portal\liferay-portal-6.2.10.1-ee-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
    </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>
</project>
```

But while i perform a build i get the below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1:build-css
>   (default) on project myNewProject: null: MojoExecutionException:
>   NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1:build-css
>   (default) on project myNewProject: null
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)

My questions are:

What is it causing a null pointer exception while i am performing the build?

Comment: Does you pom file contain a version? Can you show the full pom file? Which Maven version do you use? How have you called Maven? Have you called Maven from command line or from within an IDE?

Comment: There should be a more concrete stacktrace somewhere in your log, that shows the exact position of the NullPointerException (something with `com.liferay.maven...`)

Comment: @khmarbaise : I have added my pom.xml in my question...I am using Maven using IDE...And i  am doing the build process using IDE. Please guide.

Comment: Have you tried to run your build on command line and not from within IDE. Which Maven Version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise : i am using apache maven 3.1.1 ..And not yet tried over command prompt as i have been doing it on IDE.

Comment: Please try in command line. Which IDE? Eclipse? Which Version of it? Which Version m2e in case of Eclipse?

Comment: @khmarbaise : I tried using command prompt but was fetching the same result.  I am using Eclipse Liferay Developer Studio

Version: 2.0.0.201401271217-b1.. Can this be maven version issue?

Comment: You have defined a profile with a version `7.0.0-m2`for liferay plugin but the run shows `liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1`. You should check that you alway use the same version of the plugin.

Comment: Can you please come over chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78385/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-30329108-mojoexecutionexception-while-doing-a

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened on my Mac.

I used JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` to switch to JDK 8

`echo $JAVA_HOME` shows

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Turns out this JDK version is problematic.

I fixed it by using `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_341.jdk/Contents/Home` (after installing an official JDK8)

Now `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_341.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all you need to check the liferay version that you are using if it is mentioned in your `pom.xml`.
2. Also, the error can be thrown when you try to build your Liferay project using an old version of `Maven`. Check your Maven Version that you are using using command

   mvn -version

Also the `JDK` that you are using should be correctly mentioned in your POM.xml.
I find comment from khmarbaise as correct because the version might also have been conflicted. Hope this helps.